# R studio error: Can't save and can't write csv

Tags: r, save

I'm having issues savings R scripts. Also, the write.csv function fails to work. I get the error message below when I try to save an existing R script

[image]

I get the following error message when I try to save a new R script

[image]

I get the following error when I use write.csv
[image]

Sometimes, these errors just disappear and then they reappear again.

Attempted solutions that did not work:
-Restart computer
-Uninstall/Reinstall R studio (latest version)

Please kindly suggest what the issue is and how I may resolve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be permission based. Are you maybe trying to write into a directory where you have no access rights? What is the output of

```
home <- path.expand("~")
print(home)
file.access(home, 0)
file.access(home, 1)
file.access(home, 2)
file.access(home, 4)
```

?

If the output is looking good (correct path and zeros everywhere else), this may require multiple troubleshooting steps to figure out. But it may have something to do with Antivirus Software denying access rights as Scott Reves figured out on the R-community board (https://community.rstudio.com/t/access-denied-for-all-r-and-rstudio-activities-but-not-other-apps-in-previously-used-folders/11661).

Comment: no, I do have access right to write into that folder. The unusual part is that this error sometimes disappears on the exact same code. Then it reappears again after a while.

Comment: the output: > print(home)
[1] "C:/Users/AYingrotetar/Documents"
> file.access(home, 0)
C:/Users/AYingrotetar/Documents 
                              0 
> file.access(home, 1)
C:/Users/AYingrotetar/Documents 
                              0 
> file.access(home, 2)
C:/Users/AYingrotetar/Documents 
                              0 
> file.access(home, 4)
C:/Users/AYingrotetar/Documents 
                              0

However, I just ran this when saving works fine now.

Comment: Output looks good. Then this may require multiple troubleshooting steps. Another user on the R-community forum has posted a (kind of) similar issue and a solution as well. It seems that his Antivirus / Defender was the cause.
(https://community.rstudio.com/t/access-denied-for-all-r-and-rstudio-activities-but-not-other-apps-in-previously-used-folders/11661)

Comment: A conflict with an anti-virus or a cloud sharing system like OneDrive would be my first suspects.